# Average difference in days between dates from two datetime columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I've seen a few of these types of questions on stackoverflow, but they don't quite fit in with my question:

Is this a valid query to see the average difference in days between two dates from two datetime columns?

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(DATE(datetime_column1),DATE(datetime_column2)))
FROM table_name
WHERE status = 2
```

Further, I am wanting to group by another column, e.g.

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(DATE(datetime_column1),DATE(datetime_column2))),grouping_column
FROM table_name
WHERE status = 2
GROUP BY grouping_column
```

Comment: There might be some "off-by-one" issues.  If the two dates are on the same day, is that "0" or "1" days?

Comment: You can drop the `DATE()` functions, since `DATEDIFF()` only uses the date portion anyway.

Comment: Why are you asking if this is valid? Can't you run it? Did return values you didn't like?